# Loop summarize & quantile an function with dynamic column

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am quite new to R and I am encountering a problem. I would like to - but can't manage to - loop the following code to repeat the following for multiple columns, ideally specified by name.

```
bplist<- df %>%
   group_by(Date, X, Y, Z) %>%
   summarize(bp= quantile(THIS, probs = (1 - var)))
```

Neither bplist$THIS, nor df$THIS, nor either[x] is working.

Later, I would need it to loop through the columns again with the following idea:

```
  XY <- df%>%
    left_join(bp, by = c("A", "B", "C")) %>%
    mutate(CDE = case_when(
      THIS>= bp1~ "High",
      THIS<= bp2~ "Low",
```

But I can't seem to manage to adress the columns by a variable with their name (as "THIS" would only take a numeric vector inthe quantile function), nor by creating a vector, as this tells me that:

"Can't subset columns past the end.

Loacations [various numbers] don't exist.

There is only one Column"

Is there even any chance to automate this, preferredly using a for loop, as I am familiar with it. It don't think the looping itself will eb the problem, but adressing the columns.

Sincere thanks to anyone taking their time to read and think about this. If I left anything unclear, which I probably have as my knowledge of R is very basic, please ask.

Comment: look into `dplyr::across()` that should help you summarize multiple columns. Probably no need for a loop.

Comment: @AndS. Thank you, I will definately look into that! As there will be more happening in that loop and given that the rest of the code is - thank god - running well, I'd prefer if there was any way to make this work using the for loop. As I said, the loop itself won't be the problem (I think), but accessing the column by a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a loop, then I would make a summarizing function and then loop through the variables. I assume you want to use a character vector for the names, so this requires a little magic with dplyr using `!!`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sum_fun <- function(THIS){
  df %>%
   group_by(Date, X, Y, Z) %>%
   summarize(bp= quantile(!!quo(!!sym(THIS)), probs = (1 - var)))
}

vars <- c("A", "B", "C")
bplist <- list()

for(i in seq_along(vars)){
  bplist[[i]] <- sum_fun(vars[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Especially the "!!quo(!!sym(THIS))" was of great help, as I managed to implement the loop using this directly. I had already tried !!sym(THIS), which didn't work though. TBH, I don't know what either does, but as I am unter quite a time pressure, I'm just glad it works. Might look into it (and attend a formal R course) after the project.